# Flask - use jinja macros without a template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a Flask app that looks as follows:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    headline = render_template('headline.html', headline = 'xyz') #-> return <h1>xyz</h1>
    return render_template('page.html', headline = headline) # insert headline html into a page
```

`headline.html` is a template which imports a jinja macro from a macro file (`macros.html`). The macro generates the headline.

`headline.html`:

```
{% import 'macros.html' as macros %}
{{ macros.get_headline(headline) }}
```

`macros.html`:

```
{% macro get_headline(headline) %}
<h1>{{ healine }}</h1>
{% endmacro %}
```

My question is - is it possible to call the macro to get `headline` *without the need to call the template* `headline.html`?

Ideally, I'd like to see

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    headline = # somehow call get_headline('xyz') from macros.html
    return render_template('page.html', headline = headline) # insert headline html into a page
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rendering the template from a file, you can render a template from a string. So you can call your macro from a string.

```py
from flask.templating import render_template_string

@app.route('/')
def index():
    headline = render_template_string(
        "{% import 'macros.html' as macros %}"
        "{{ macros.get_headline(headline) }}",
        headline='xyz'
    )
    return render_template('page.html', headline=headline)
```

<sub>(ignoring the typo `healine` instead of `headline` in macros.html)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

> My question is - is it possible to call the macro to get `headline` *without the need to call the template* `headline.html`?

I hope you figured out your situation. My bet is you'll eventually settle on a better way to do this than what you're proposing, which seems a bit backwards to me, but hey, that's part of the learning process!

Especially for simple text transformation functions that only take a single argument, you may get better mileage from a Python function that you register as a Jinja filter with `Environment.filters` as described [here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#custom-filters). It's less syntax all around, and you can use the same function from Python *and* your Jinja templates in a standard way, without hacks.

That said, I blundered into the [`.module` property](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#jinja2.Template.module) on Jinja templates just today. It allows you to call macros from a template as regular Python functions:

`macros.html`:

```html
{% macro get_headline(headline) -%}
<h1>{{ headline }}</h1>
{%- endmacro %}
```

`test.py`:

```py
# these imports not needed for a Flask app
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

# just use `app.jinja_env` for a Flask app
e = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('.'))
t = e.get_template('macros.html')

t.module.get_headline('Headline')
# >>> '<h1>Headline</h1>'
```

I believe (?) this does what you were originally asking, with the `app.jinja_env` environment that you already have with Flask, and no extra imports.